# Weblogic 12c deploy error with CXF web app: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, deployment, cxf, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy a simple CXF web service app to WebLogic 12c. This CXF app runs fine on Tomcat v9.0.

I get the deployment error below when I try to activate the installation in the WLS 12c console

```
<Mar 24, 2020 1:56:21,866 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <myserver> <MSvr1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '21' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <28078776-c663-4758-859c-57a95e259a96-0000087f> <1585072581866> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1616440100713499" for task "145" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class"
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
              at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:132)
              at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:244)
              at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
              at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:242)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:800)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1352)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:270)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
              at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
              at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
              at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
              at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678)
              at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
              at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
              at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
              at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
              at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
              at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
              at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
Caused By: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
              at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1046)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1038)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:101)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:71)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
              at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1046)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1038)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:101)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:71)
              at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
              at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.loadClass(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:366)
              at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.access$100(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:58)
              at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow$CollectorFilter.accept(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:341)
              at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getAnnotatedClasses(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:720)
              at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getAnnotatedClassesByTargetsAndSources(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:664)
              at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getAnnotatedClassesByTargetsAndSources(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:639)
              at weblogic.servlet.internal.War$CompositeClassInfoFinder.getAnnotatedClassesByTargetsAndSources(War.java:836)
              at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processAnnotations(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:288)
              at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processPOJOsInModuleScopes(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:229)
              at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.prepare(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:73)
              at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
              at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
              at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
              at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
              at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:242)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:800)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1352)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:270)
              at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
              at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
              at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
              at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
              at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678)
              at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
              at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
              at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
              at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
              at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
              at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
              at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
>
```

Here is my META-INF/weblogic-application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application
    xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd
    http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">

    <wls:application-param>
        <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
        <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
    </wls:application-param>

    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.wsdl.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.cxf.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.jws.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>

</wls:weblogic-application>
```

I am deploying the app as an .ear file with all the CXF libraries packaged in the war inside the /lib directory.

Should I install the CXF libraries on WebLogic and take them out of the .ear/.war?